# Beginner Flask/Jinja2 - Extends/Block not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

So I'm trying to put a block in my original layout but can't figure out how to make it work.

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
 </head>

 <body>
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock content %}
 </body>

</html>
```

projects.html

```
    {% extends 'home.html' %}

    {% block content %}

   <h6> HEY! </h6>

    {% endblock content %}
```

I've tried to replace the `{% endblock content %}` in the two files by just `{% endblock %}`, didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256188/jinja-not-executing-html-in-django-web-application-runtimeerror

Comment: @Oqhax I found the solution for me. You're using Django so it might be another problem, but for me, I just had to change my python file from `return render_template('home.html')` to `render_template('projects.html')`. Basically your primary rendered template should be the block that you include, NOT the original template homepage. Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: @Oqhax you do *not* have the same problem. As I commented on that post, your question has nothing to do with Jinja2; and anyway, Bill has given you an answer. Why don't you accept that rather than commenting here?

Comment: include the code that renders `projects.html`

Comment: your code looks fine, if there is a problem, you should look in the view for it. please show us the code in the view rendering the page.

Answer (score 1):

im looking for a different problem but yours is endblock dont worry about the block name so it would be

`{% block content &} and {% endblock %}`